# mini pop-up validator (like html require)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Does anyone know a validator that displays the error in a mini pop-up (like html require but with the possibility to add a stronger condition).

I searched for like 1/2 hour and found only with errors next to field/under field/whatever.

Note: I am working for an existing solution and don't care about what validation rules are included since I'm going to write my own anyway. Only thing I need is that cute little bubble with a customized message.

Comment: how about `alert();` with `return false;` on validation fail?

Comment: Yes but I said "Cute little bubble" not "Big bad alert" :)

Comment: well, soon I'll publish such a plugin for jQuery, lol.

Comment: Well, it is not authored as a plugin yet and it's not documented. But I can give you the "raw" code. Is there a "Private message" option?

Comment: Try this one: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/ The documentation is a bit lacking, but it works nicely.